# Turning an iOS framework into Cocoapod - do I need a new repo? Does it have to build a static library?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an Objetive-C project that builds an iOS framework. It is currently in a subfolder in a git repo hosted on github. I want to distribute the code that is in the iOS framework as a Cocoapod. I have a couple of specific questions.

First, do I need to make a  separate repo with just the code for the framework?

Second, does Cocoapods always build my code into a static library? It is OK if that is the case - static libraries are fine - but I'll have to make changes that affect other projects if we are switching from a framework (which is ultimately a dynamic library) to a static library. I would prefer to know whether it is possible to have Cocoapods build a framework and whether that is a good idea or more trouble than its worth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tell you what I've done in my projects.

> I have an Objetive-C project that builds an iOS framework

So you already know hot to make a framework. Otherwise I would have suggest you to read these wonderful tutorial from [www.raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com)

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/2430-how-to-create-a-framework-for-ios

> First, do I need to make a separate repo with just the code for the
>   framework?

**For my development**

I've done a **separate repo** with all the framework/library (shared code) and added it as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in my project(s).

```
git submodule add https://github.com/me/MyFramework
```

When I brand new clone my project I init my submodules with this commands:

```
git submodule update --init --remote
git submodule foreach git checkout master // this only if you wanna the master commit and not be in a detach state
```

You can also lock a submodule to a particular commit or tag or branch of your separate repo by adding

```
branch = commit|tag|branch
```

in your `.gitmodules` file

I've made the framework as a Framework `Pod` as explained here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios

And I use it as a **development pod** by specifying in my main project `Podfile` the path as a *relative pat* `'../my_framework_pod'`

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MyMainAwsomeProject' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'MyFramework', :path => '../MyFramework'

end
```

If you wanna import it not as development pod (the code will be readonly) you could put the git repo URI instead of the relative path.

> Second, does Cocoapods always build my code into a static library?

To be honest, I've always seen it as a static library. But this is the static library of the whole of all the Pods you are using in the main project.

But it should be quite painless for you as you need only to change how to use it. By adding your framework to the Podfile along with all the other Pods you are already using.

You would add it only to your main project `Podfile` and when you type `pod install` it's up to the `pod` command to create the correct workspace.

Hope to have shown you a valid and nice journey to make.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is helpful.